# Getting Input values of Strike Input Component in a Parent Component Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I am using Strike Input component as child componet to capture Input Field as below:

```
<c:strike_input auraId="groupName" value="{!v.group.Name}" type="text" name="Name" label="Group Name" errorMessage="Invalid Group Name"/>
```

Now in the parent component controller i want to get the value of this input user entered but i am not sure how can i do it. I have registered to an event in the parent component like below:

```
<aura:handler name="onchange" event="c:strike_evt" action="{!c.strikeInputChanged}" />
```

And in the parent controller:

```
strikeInputChanged: function(component, event, helper) {
        var groupObj = component.get("v.groupData");
        groupObj.GroupName =  component.find("inputField").get("v.value");     
        component.set("v.groupData", groupObj);
    },
```

But `component.find("inputField").get("v.value")` is returning null. I have also tried with `component.find("groupName").get("v.value");` but same result.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, that strike is using their own `auraId` did you also try using `aura:id`?

Comment: I think aura:id is with Lightining:input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since strike already defined an `onchange` event:

```
<!-- strike_input.cmp -->
<aura:registerEvent name="onchange" type="c:strike_evt"/>
```

you can just use it like this:

```
<c:strike_input onchange="{!c.strikeInputChanged}" value="{!v.group.Name}"/>
```

And catch the events Element to get its value like this:

```
strikeInputChanged: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.getSource().get("v.value");
    ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks it helps. But i am getting another issue for which i am creating another question.

Comment: I created my next question [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200243/action-failed-error-on-onchange-cstrike-input-event-cstrike-evt)