# Action Failed error on 'onchange' c:strike_input event (c:strike_evt)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Following my this question [Getting Strike Input Component field value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200237/getting-input-values-of-strike-input-component-in-a-parent-component-controller), I am getting following error whenever I change text in any input field:

[image]

c:strike_input is as it is provided component and i am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved when I provided default values to the fields in the Init event function, like below:

```
({
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    var accountInfo = {
        'Name': 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America',
        'AccountNumber': 'B65609253',
        'ba_LegalEntityName__c': 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America',
        'ba_GroupStatus__c': 'Prospect',
        'Ownership': 'Private',
        'Sic': 'a0e0P00000CnJu3QAF',
        'ba_RatingZipcode__c': 'a0l0P00001IUgg5QAD',
        'ba_RatingCounty__c': 'Miami-Dade',
        'ba_RatingCity__c': 'Pinecrest'
    };        

    component.set("v.group",accountInfo);        
}})
```